# How to properly do monkey Patching on Django 3.1

Tags: python, django

i'm currently coding a web application with django 3.0 and trying to override some functions of an installed django apps (Python social auth module). I want to do it because i want to change the default behavior.

I have found some method to perform overriding of a module (monkey patching) and try to implement it but i the following errors when i try to implement it :

```
  File "/Users/***********/code/recrutlocataire/recrutlocataire/core/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import core.monkey
  File "/Users/***********/code/recrutlocataire/recrutlocataire/core/monkey.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.sessions.base_session import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/base_session.py", line 26, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseSession(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 107, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Create my patch in the monkey.py file in my application directory:

core/monkey.py

```
from social_core import utils
from social_core.exceptions import InvalidEmail
from django.core import signing
from django.core.signing import BadSignature
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
from django.conf import settings

def partial_pipeline_data(backend, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
  pass
```

Import the monkey file in the init file located in my application directory :

core/**init**.py

```
import core.monkey
```

It seems that I have this error because I'm trying to import the session module whereas the application loading is not done but i cannot find a proper way to do it.

Could someone tell me how can I perform it properly please ?